# Some questions about angular2 providers

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Sorry, I'm new in programming and haven't one's friend, who knew the topic, so I'm going to flood stackoverflow by my silly questions.

I can set providers on bootstrap level

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [Service]);
```

In rootComponent

```
@Component({
    providers: [Service],
    //...
```

Or on sub-component level.

Questions for this time:

1. I'll simplify, but if someService set's as a provider for someComponent, is it means that someComponent have fields and methods of someService? 
   Provider provide service's methods and fields for component to instantiate new instance?
2. deleted
3. And if I provide service, its methods somehow can be called on lower level?
4. And if someComponent inject someService, in which injected someService2, do I need to set as provider both of them [someService, someService2] on level of someComponent? And if I already inject someService2 somewere or/and in upper-level-component?
5. Why HTTP_PROVIDERS set's up in bootstrap-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **3.**

Dependency injection is hierarchical

```
bootstrap()
|-app-component
  |-sub-component1
  |-sub-component2
    |-sub-sub-component21
```

When a component or service instantiated by Angulars DI, it checks what parameters the constructor expects and tries to look up a matching provider.

When `sub-sub-component` is created and it has a constructor like `constructor(myService: MyService)`, DI starts looking from `sub-sub-components` providers upward if it finds a matching provider. If it reaches `bootstrap() and still hasn't found one it fails with an error message.

For each level in the hierarchy only one instance of a provider is created.
When `MyService` is registered as provider in `bootstrap()`, then any component that requests a `MyService`, will get passed in the same instance created in `bootstrap()`.

When `MyService` is **also** registered in `sub-component2`, then when `sub-sub-component` requests a `MyService` it will get the one from `sub-component2` because this is the first it finds. When `sub-component1` also requests a `MyService` DI would return the one of `bootstrap()` because the hierarchy upwards there is nothing else providing `MyService`.

If you want to share some data with the whole application, only register the service you want to use use to share the data at `bootstrap()`.

> **1.**

If a component ('sub-component') has a constructor like

```
export class SubComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  }

  someName: string;

  clickHandler($event) {
    this.myService.clickHappended = true;
    this.someName = this.myService.loadNameFromServer();
  }
}
```

then a reference to a `MyService` is assigned to `myService` and code in `SubComponent` can read and write `MyServices`s fields and call its methods.

> **4.** And if someComponent inject someService, in which injected someService2, do I need to set as provider both of them [someService, someService2] on level of someComponent? And if I already inject someService2 somewere or/and in upper-level-component?

When a component class or service class is created by Angular, it uses DI. It looks up the providers for the requested type and creates an instance or uses an existing one. When DI creates an instance it checks the constructors of that type and looks up providers again for these types. This goes recursively at arbitrary levels, (even in cycles where DI needs some help)

So, short answer: yes. Everything that gets injected by DI needs a registered provider.

> **5.** Why HTTP_PROVIDERS set's up in bootstrap-level?

The classes provides by `HTTP_PROVIDERS` can be reused by the whole application. There is no need to create a new instance for each HTTP request and no need for each component or service to have its own instance of the `Http` class. If you want a specific component to use a different `Http` class, you can add that specific `Http` class to the providers list of that component. This component and all its sub-components will use this provider instead.

```
export class MySpecialHttp {
}

@Component(selector: 'sub-sub',
   providers: [provide(Http, {useClass: MySpecialHttp})]
export class SubSubComponent {
  constructor(http: Http) {}
}
```

Here we instruct DI, that when `SubSubComponent` or one of it's child-components requests `Http`, pass in `MySpecialHttp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Hierarchical Injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) from the dev guide.  It will answer most of your questions.

When a component has a `providers: [MyService]` line, it means that this component and all children will share the same/single instance of the service.

If a service needs to inject another service, it will look up the component tree to find a provider for that needed service, and it will use whichever one it finds first.

HTTP_PROVIDERS is often set up in bootstrap because we often only want one instance of these classes/services.